# How to get workgroup name in Samba?

Tags: samba

Given IP or host name, is there a way to get workgroup name by libsmbclient API or Samba command in Linux?

I already knew that how to browse workgroups, servers and shares by libsmbclient API.

Sometimes not all servers in LAN can be found by libsmbclient API. I don't know the root cause yet.